# Giving 2 parameters to remote_function using 'with'

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony1

I'm trying to give several parameters in a `remote_function` like this:

```
<?php 
echo remote_function(array( 'update' => 'test',
                           'url' => 'conges/verifdate',
                           'with' => "'date_deb=' + $('date_debut').value"
                    ));
?>
```

This code works (in my `action.class` I can get the parameter).

But when I try to give a second parameter, it doesn't work:

```
<?php
    echo remote_function(array( 'update' => 'test',
                           'url' => 'conges/verifdate',
                           'with' => "'date_deb=' + $('date_debut').value"."'+&date_fin=' + $('date_fin')"
                    ))
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
'url' => 'conges/verifdate?vars=serialize(array("var1" => 1, "var2" => 2))'
```

In your remote action you do:

```
$vars = unserialize($request->getParameter('vars'));
```

Comment: I saw you I missunderstood your question, maybe this link is helpful: http://onrails.org/articles/2006/05/01/remote_function-with